# link to custom .php files in wordpress theme

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I need  assistance on setting up my html template to wordpress theme

I have an HTML Template that I want to convert to wordpress theme, and have taken some steps:

- creating some files, like style.css  which contain my css, index.php, function.php and some other page file

Whenever I load [my website](https://digitalbangs.com/) it only loads the index.php file, I  have been trying to navigate to the other pages but can't seem to. If I click on any link it displays the index page.

Comment: Do you have activated the theme you've created?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that when you say you 'created some files' you actually mean that you **properly** [created a custom WordPress theme](https://www.dreamhost.com/wordpress/guide-to-developing-a-wp-theme/).

My guess is that this issue is most likely tied to your permalink settings.  There are some good [posts on how to set these up properly](https://www.hostgator.com/help/article/links-on-wordpress-all-redirect-back-to-home-page) around.

Finally, if that doesn't work then I suspect your `.htaccess` file is the issue.  Have you checked that your file exists and [is configured properly](https://www.hostinger.com/tutorials/create-default-wordpress-htaccess-file)?  You can also read more about .htaccess properties [here](https://themeisle.com/blog/htaccess-file-in-wordpress/).